# Few quick Mathematica questions about Dictionary

Tags: assignment

*a. Get the list whose elements are of the form {language,number of words in dictionary)*

I tried this, and it gave me the number if words in dictionary, but I don't know how to get the language part:

```
lang = DictionaryLookup[All];

langlength =Table[{lang[[i]], Length[DictionaryLookup[{lang[[i]], All}]]}, {i, 1,
Length[lang]}]
```

*b. Now sort this list in descending order by the number of words and get a list of the form* `{position in sorted list, language, number of words}`.

For part b, I have

```
sorted = Sort[langlength, #1[[2]] >= #2[[2]] &]
placeList[list_] := Table[{i, list[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[list]}] 
pl = placeList[sorted]
```

And I got

> {1, {"Finnish", 728498}, 2, {"Catalan", 602208}, 3, {"Galician", 
>     515385}, 4, {"Portuguese", 459996}, 5, {"Hebrew", 
>     455264}, 6, {"Danish", 376469}, 7, {"BrazilianPortuguese", 
>     264713}, 8, {"Croatian", 260752}, 9, {"Polish", 
>     234907}, 10, {"Hungarian", 230206}, 11, {"Dutch", 
>     229368}, 12, {"French", 139657}, 13, {"Swedish", 
>     121430}, 14, {"Italian", 116854}, 15, {"Faroese", 
>     108508}, 16, {"English", 92518}, 17, {"BritishEnglish", 
>     86135}, 18, {"Spanish", 86016}, 19, {"German", 
>     76155}, 20, {"IrishGaelic", 65203}, 21, {"Arabic", 
>     43768}, 22, {"Breton", 32733}, 23, {"Russian", 31801}, 24, {"Hindi",
>      15983}, 25, {"ScottishGaelic", 15670}, 26, {"Esperanto", 
>     14780}, 27, {"Latin", 8777}}`

From here I don't know how to get rid of the braces around `Finnish, 728498` and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
langlength = ({#, Length@DictionaryLookup[{#, All}]} & /@ DictionaryLookup[All]);
lst = Sort[langlength, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &];
TableForm[lst, TableHeadings -> {Range[Length[lst]], None}]
```

**Edit**

```
langlength = ({#, Length@DictionaryLookup[{#, All}]} & /@ DictionaryLookup[All]);
lst = Sort[langlength, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &];
placeList = Table[{i, lst[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[lst]}]
TableForm[placeList, TableDepth -> 2]
```

Comment: I actually figured out part a.
For part b, I have placeList[list_] := Table[{i, list[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[list]}]

Comment: **@molekyla777**
Can you help me with part b. I already figured out most of the part. I just need to get rid of those braces.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer your question by first clarifying some of the fundamentals about *Mathematica*:

**A. Mapping over list.** If you have a function, you can apply it to a list of values by using `Map`:

```
Range[10]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

```
Map[Sqrt, Range[10]]
```

> $\left\{1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},2,\sqrt{5},\sqrt{6},\sqrt{7},2 \sqrt{2},3,\sqrt{10}\right\}$

You can do it with your own functions as well:

```
f[n_] := n^2 + 1 (* this function squares it's argument and adds 1 *);
Map[f, Range[10]]
```

> {2, 5, 10, 17, 26, 37, 50, 65, 82, 101}

**B. Return values.** You own functions can return any kind of value, including a list:

```
f[n_] := {n, n^2, N[Sqrt[n]]} (* returns a list of three elements: a number, 
                                 it's square and it's square root *)
Map[f, Range[10]]
```

Here, you get a *list of lists* as a result:

> {{1, 1, 1.}, {2, 4, 1.41421}, {3, 9, 1.73205}, {4, 16, 2.}, {5, 25, 
>     2.23607}, {6, 36, 2.44949}, {7, 49, 2.64575}, {8, 64, 2.82843}, {9, 
>     81, 3.}, {10, 100, 3.16228}}

**C. Solving (a).** For your first question, you seem to know already how to return a list of all languages known to *Mathematica*

```
DictionaryLookup[All]
```

> {"Arabic", "BrazilianPortuguese", "Breton", "BritishEnglish", 
>   "Catalan", "Croatian", "Danish", "Dutch", "English", "Esperanto", 
>   "Faroese", "Finnish", "French", "Galician", "German", "Hebrew", 
>   "Hindi", "Hungarian", "IrishGaelic", "Italian", "Latin", "Polish", 
>   "Portuguese", "Russian", "ScottishGaelic", "Spanish", "Swedish"}

as well as how to get a list of the form `{language,number of words in dictionary}`

```
wordsInLanguage[lang_] := {lang, Length[DictionaryLookup[{lang, All}]]}
wordsInLanguage["Russian"]
```

> {"Russian", 31801}

so you can just use Map to get what your need in *(a)*:

```
Map[wordsInLanguage, DictionaryLookup[All]]
```

> {{"Arabic", 43768}, {"BrazilianPortuguese", 264713}, {"Breton", 
>     32733}, {"BritishEnglish", 86135}, {"Catalan", 602208}, {"Croatian",
>      260752}, {"Danish", 376469}, {"Dutch", 229368}, {"English", 
>     92518}, {"Esperanto", 14780}, {"Faroese", 108508}, {"Finnish", 
>     728498}, {"French", 139657}, {"Galician", 515385}, {"German", 
>     76155}, {"Hebrew", 455264}, {"Hindi", 15983}, {"Hungarian", 
>     230206}, {"IrishGaelic", 65203}, {"Italian", 116854}, {"Latin", 
>     8777}, {"Polish", 234907}, {"Portuguese", 459996}, {"Russian", 
>     31801}, {"ScottishGaelic", 15670}, {"Spanish", 86016}, {"Swedish", 
>     121430}}

**D. Flattening lists.** Now, to answer your second question, you need to learn how to flatten lists. For example, given a list `{1, 2}`, how can you get a list `{1, 2, 3}`?

There are quite a few ways:

```
(* works if you know that the list only contains two elements *)
addThirdElement[list_, element_] := {list[[1]], list[[2]], element}
addThirdElement[{1, 2}, 3]
```

> {1, 2, 3}

Another option is this - you can even reorder elements in the list:

```
addThirdElement1[{first_, second_}, third_] := {third, second, first}
addThirdElement1[{1, 2}, 3]
```

> {3, 2, 1}

There are many more - e.g. look up `Flatten` in *Mathematica* documentation.

That should give you enough to solve the last part. Good luck!

Comment: I actually have trouble with the "Flatten" command. I tried quite a few times, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to get help, you would first need to explain: 1) What have you tried (with code); 2) What do you expect; 3) What did you receive instead. You don't need to use `Flatten` to solve (b) - just try to read and understand the section `D` above.

Comment: I tried `Flatten[pl,1]` and `Flatten[pl,2]`, but none of these worked. And if you look at my part b, you'd know what is pl, in my case.

Comment: Let's read `Flatten` documentation together. What does it do?

Comment: Well, it flattens list to a certain level

Comment: That's right. It flattens a list to a certain level. Now, what do you need to flatten?

Comment: I need to get rid of those braces around `Finnish, 728498` and the rest of them.

Comment: This is certainly what you need to _achieve_, but can you rephrase it in terms of which _lists_ you need to flatten? Can you give me an example?

Comment: This is what I am saying. That's the problem. I don't know which `list` I need to `flatten`

Comment: Can you flatten this list: `{1, {"Finnish", 728498}}`? This is the first element of your `pl`.

Comment: Yes, I can. `con={1,{"Finnish,728498}}`
`Flatten[con,2]`
And I got `{1,Finnish,728498}`

Comment: Great. Of even `Flatten[con]` will work. Now you know how to flatten **first** element of your list `pl`. What would you do to apply it to **every** element of your list `pl`? **Hint**: read my answer above.

Comment: Need to go, but I'm sure you'll solve it now.